# Save date in MSSQL without day and month

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a php-project, where i need to save birthdates which my have no day and/or month.
For example: 1980-00-00

In mysql this works without any problems, but i cant find a way to save this date in MSSQL

Comment: Because that is not a date. Use NULL (or some other "flag" value) to indicate that a value is not provided. Different database engines have different rules about what is allowed.

Comment: Just setting NULL does not help, because in this case i definitely need the birth-year.

Comment: Use a column with data type = integer

Comment: *"In mysql this works without any problems"* That because, (for some silly reason) MySQL supports dates that don't have a month or day. That is not standard behaviour. If you only want to store a year, then use a `smallint` column instead. If you're storing this in a date and time column, then store an appropriate date or perhaps you should have 2 columns; a start and end date (and time).

Comment: Considering this is for birth dates, then I would (personally) suggest that in the circumstances of not knowing the month/day you *assume* the 1st until told otherwise. `1980-00-00` = `1980-01-01` and `1990-05-00` = `1990-05-01`. If you want to flag that the date of birth isn't confirmed, add a `bit` column, to store this meta data.

Comment: In MySQL it isn't guaranteed to work out of the box: you need to ensure there's a certain SQL mode enabled for your current session and, if I'm not wrong, it hasn't been the default for several years now.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL when inserting that date field to a table, insert it to a `date` data type column on some table. 1980-00-00 is not a valid date so you will need to do something with the "invalid" value: You can use a **case** to convert it to null or whatever value you'd like on the fly; `case when datefield = '1980-00-00'  then null else datefield end`

You could also do something with `ISDATE` and check if the date field is valid. If its not valid default it to 01-01. You have options. It looks like there is a valid year so you could extract that and use it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
case when isdate(datefield) = 0 then cast(substring(datefield,1,4) + '-01-01'  as date) else datefield end
```